# Ways to Tie with foreign key WITH primary key on SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

Im working on database design on ***Microsoft Sql server management Studio***, I have a small problem.  A LibraryItem should have a required category tied with a foreign key of CategoryId mapped to Id in the table Category as shown in the picture.

[SEE THE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abTCc.png)

[SECOND IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd6Nr.png)

I need help with how I can tie CategoryId(FK) to Id(PK on Category Table). I just dont know how to do it excatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add the reference to the script that creates the table and add a name to the constraint like so:

```sql
CONSTRAINT FK_LibraryItem_Category_CategoryId FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([Id])
```

Note: I've defaulted to the `dbo` schema. You will need to change that if it's different for the Category table you are creating.

That will create a Foreign Key for your LibraryItem table and link the CategoryId to the respective record in the Category table.

Another thing to note as well: This will throw errors if your value for the FK doesn't match an ID in the Category table.

To ellaborate on the errors:

Let's say you add a `CategoryId` of 2 to a record in your `LibraryItem` table but a record with the `ID` of 2 doesn't exist in your `Category` table, it will throw an error similar to this:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_LibraryItem_Category_CategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "foo", table "dbo.LibraryItem". The statement has been terminated.
```

This can be easily solved by ensuring the IDs match in both tables.

Comment: If the FK dosent match? What do you mean? Could be more clear please.

Comment: @Dell97 updated to answer your additional question.

Comment: I understand, could you please check the SECOND IMAGE above, to tell me if I did it right. I've updated my question.

Comment: Yeah that looks correct to me. Good work :). I would recommend testing it by adding a record when you can with an `INSERT` script.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I'll keep an eye out for any questions you might have regarding this and will try to help out where I can. Good luck with your interview and you'll do just fine. Using resources around the net is a great way to show initiative as well so you'll do just fine.